# Use of Jquery 1.10 with Known Vulnerability

Tags: magento2, jquery, vulnerability

We launched a website 2 weeks ago and our client launch a pen test to check if everything was safe.
Unfortunately It looks that we have two issues because of :

- Vulnerable javascript library: jQuery.ui.dialog : version: 1.10.4
  script uri: //static/version1586970304/frontend/Sm/market/fr_BE/jquery/patches/jquery-ui.js
- Vulnerable javascript library: jQuery version: 1.12.4
  script uri: //static/version1586970304/frontend/Sm/market/fr_BE/jquery.js

Is it real breach? 
Can we do something to solve it?
I'm a bit afraid of updating the library since it will ask a lot of work.

Many thanks for your help!
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jquery issue is fixed with a simple patch

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2432#issuecomment-403761229

It sounds severe but really is a minor issue

https://www.cadence-labs.com/2018/07/magento-outdated-jquery-version-how-to-patch-without-upgrading-cve-2015-9251/

```
// auto-execution of scripts when no explicit dataType was provided (See gh-2432)
jQuery.ajaxPrefilter( function( s ) {
    if ( s.crossDomain ) {
        s.contents.script = false;
    }
});
```

You can then run the snippet of code with the xss check:

`jQuery.get('https://sakurity.com/jqueryxss');`

If you’ve correctly implemented the patch, you should no longer see a popup.

Not sure about the jQuery.ui.dialog part

Should be safe to upgrade that

Magento team dont seen too concerned

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14238

Comment: Hello Dominic,

Indeed I found the patch on the website and I don't see the popup.

Thanks a lot for your answer !
Have a great day and be save